# converting string from input to decimal property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm taking user input from winform. One of this inputs is decimal.

I should convert this value to decimal property.

My text box is txtPrice and property is myArticle.Price, so I tried like this

```
myArticle.Price = decimal.Parse(txtPrice.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and I'm getting runtime exception

**Input string was not in a correct format.**

Comment: As well as using `.Text` (as mentioned below) you should consider using `decimal.TryParse`, and handling the scenario where a non-numeric value gets entered by the user (showing an error message to them, for example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want the `.Text` property of `txtPrice` instead of `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

most people will advise tryParse

```
if(decimal.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, out myArticle.Price))
{
    // your string was in the incorrect format
}
```

Comment: how can I use Cultureinfo.InvariantCulture in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Text` Property of `TextBox`

```
myArticle.Price = decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```